# Excel UDF to count errors

Tags: excel, vba, count, user-defined-functions, excel-udf

I was trying to write an UDF in Excel VBA which would count errors (#NA!, #REF!...).
I tried to translate Excel formulas into VBA language bud did not succed.
Does somebody know a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
Public Function CountErr(cells As range) As Long
   Dim cell As range
   For Each cell In cells
      If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(cell) Then CountErr = CountErr + 1
   Next
End Function
```